# SQL Reporting Services - Charting last 3 months Count

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services, charts

I'm trying to create a landing page for ticketing arrival figures in SSRS; when you open the page, ideally, it would display the most recent 3 months count of tickets per month.(I'd also like to do a chart with just the current month & the count of tickets per day)

I've scoured around looking for GETDATE options as to avoid using date input parameters, but they don't seem to work in SSRS.

What I'm using as of now is:

```
Select Incident_Number, Assignee, 
CASE
datepart(m, dateadd(second,Submit_Date,'1969-12-31 16:00:00'))
WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Febuary'
WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
END as SubmitDate1

FROM Tbl_TABLE
WHERE (Assigned_Group = 'My Group'
```

I'll then take the SubmitDate1 & do a count off of it for my chart.

Any ideas on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After playing with the report, I was able to chart what I needed utilizing Default Parameters. I also figured out how to remove the CASE from my query:
    `Select
    datename(m, dateadd(second,Submit_Date,'1969-12-31 16:00:00'))
    as SubmitDate1
    From TBL_Table 
    Where Assigned_Group = 'My Group'
    AND dateadd(second,Submit_Date,'1969-12-31 16:00:00') between 
    @StartDate and @EndDate` I then set @StartDate & @ EndDate to have default parameters to be `=DateAdd("m",-3,Today)` and `=Today()` respectively